# Put two UK visa applications into one envelope - how can I get the UK consulate to acknowledge both?

Tags: visas, uk, indian-citizens, paperwork, application-status

So when applying for a standard UK visitor visa me and a friend created individual applications (different GWF numbers) however bundled it into the same envelope when sending it to the embassy in New York

I have confirmation from UPS that the parcel has been delivered. My friend has received a confirmation mail from the embassy that his visa application is in process, its been 3 days and I still haven't received an update on my application via email.

Is this something that could be a mail room error or is it that when applications are sent together updates are only provided on one GWF number. Also, we put only one return courier label inside the envelope, will that suffice?

Any advice, clarifications at this point is much appreciated since I am getting a little nervous.

Comment: This was a bad idea. It is very unlikely that the embassy will have any mechanism to remember that these two applications from unrelated people, which require independent processing, are supposed to be then collected together and returned in the same envelope. This wasn't a "mail room error" but, rather, an applicant error.

Comment: Any way i can remedy this?

Comment: I've no idea, sorry. You could try getting in touch with the embassy, but my understanding is that they make that quite difficult to avoid getting thousands of calls asking "Is my visa nearly ready, yet?" I would _speculate_ that your application and supporting documents are currently in a folder with your friend's application and that the officer who processes your friend's application will find them. At that point, I would _guess_ that they would contact you.

Comment: No. A single return label jeopardises DPA integrity. I hope you didn't see advice like that on the net?

Comment: One thing the embassy could do, given one envelope and one return label, is to act as though there is one application, with some extraneous materials in the envelope with it. That changes it from a really weird and difficult-to-handle situation to something they must see all the time. If that is what is happening, the e-mail acknowledgement means they picked the friend's application to process. Maybe they will return the OP's papers with the result, and the OP can resend them in their own envelope with their own return label.

Comment: So on the return label is enlisted both our application numbers with my name on it, given that both applications would likely be returned together. When I called the UK visa application care team to escalate the matter, they mentioned that this is something they do see on occasions. Still am a little nervous about the whole thing since I fly out on 3 May.

Comment: Is it possible for them to process both applications but only happen to provide updates on one of the GWF numbers?

Comment: What happened in the end? Did you get a visa?

Answer (score 2):

Please use the link below to get an update on your application. They reply within one business day and also give you an update on your application. I was also getting a bit nervous because I did not get any update from the Embassy even after 15 days so I decided to mail them and received a response from them the very next day.
Goto the link below and select your country. Then select option email us and provide your application number and your concern. I have also attached a snapshot of the response that I received from the UK embassy.

https://ukvi-international.faq-help.com/

[image]